# NameError while connecting Django ForeignKey field to another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I am having this name error `NameError: name 'Profile' is not defined` while i set my ForeignKey field value. I have had experience in Django before and this error seems so nonsense. What coulde cause issue here?

my Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField('Token', default='1234a', max_length=100)
    bio = models.CharField('Bio', max_length=100, default='cool')
    name = models.CharField('Nimi', max_length=100, default='...')
    ...
```

Comment: Did you do migrations on your project ? And import the.py script containing Profile in the.py script containing Post class ?

Comment: at the moment, when i try to 'python manage.py migrate' it shows this nameerror , so i cant

Comment: Ther are a few possible causes, 
> you didn't mention your app in settings.py installed apps
> did run make migrations 
> did run migrate

Comment: i have cheked all of those, and everything is done correctly

Comment: change the order of modals, I have posted the answer. It will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Post is using Profile but you defined it after Profile that's why you are getting this error. Try this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField('Token', default='1234a', max_length=100)
    bio = models.CharField('Bio', max_length=100, default='cool')
    name = models.CharField('Nimi', max_length=100, default='...')
...
```

Then Post modal

```
class Post(models.Model):
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If it doesn't work then check following

- You mentioned app name in settings.py installed apps
- run makemigrations
- run migrate